# Jquery writing modular functions

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a main function which is called App.
It has certain public and private functions.see code below.
I want it write it in a modular way.

The problem is I want to map some private functions to public function and i am unable to do that.

**For example**;

I want to call `App.ModuleA` which should call `_A()` private functions and give me access to its public functions like  `App.ModuleA.fun_1`.

I know to make it to work; I need to make _A() as public. But is it possiple to map functions ?

How can I achieve such mapping? Can any one suggest better Coding structure So i Can access sub functions inside App and their public functions too?

For Now I am getting error `TypeError: _A is not a function` when i call `App.ModulaA();`

```
  var App = function () {
      // App Private Functions
      var _A = function () {
          return {
              fun_1: function () {
                  alert("_A.fun_1");
              },
              fun2: function () {
                  alert("_A.fun2");
              }
          };
      }();
      // App Public Functions
      return {
          init: function () {
              alert("App.init");
          },
          ModulaA: function () {
              return _A(); // doesnot work
              // return this._A(); // doesnot work                  
          }
      };
  }();

App.ModulaA();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_A() is not self invoking function, thus remove parenthesis, see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gsBQ5/)

```
}() <---- remove parenthesis
```

Comment: Can you explain ```}() ``` purpose of this ? what is meant by self invoking ? How it is useful in App definition but not in sub function _a ?

Comment: those brackets immediately executes the function, to keep things DRY see this [link](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/an-important-pair-of-parens) for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make one of two changes:

```
var _A = function() {
    //...
}();

// change to:
var _A = function() {
    //...
};
```

Or:

```
return _A();
// change to:
return _A;
```

In your example `_A` has already been evaluated so is no longer a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var App = function () {
    //App Private Functions
    var _A = function () {
        return {
            fun_1: function () {
                alert("_A.fun_1");
            },
            fun2: function () {
                alert("_A.fun2");
            }
        };
    },
    init = function () {
        alert("App.init");
    },
    ModulaA = function () {
        return _A();
    };

    // App Public Functions
    return {
        init: init,
        ModulaA: ModulaA
    };
}();

var moduleA = App.ModulaA();
moduleA.fun_1();    //Works
moduleA.fun2();    //Works
```